# Why did my house lights flicker when I was using kitchen appliances?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I was cooking in the kitchen using bake function of an air fryer for 30 minutes. Turned on the microwave for 30. Power went off on other circuits, but stayed on in the bedrooms and bathrooms.

No breakers were tripped. I manually reset the affected circuits where the power went out. Instead of normal lights, I got orange color on the bulbs that lit up. If I overloaded the kitchen circuit, why did it affect some of the other, but not all, circuits?

What will the fix entail? Thanks.

Comment: More information needed.  Where in world are you?  Age of electric circuits in house?  You know if air fryer and microwave were/are on same circuit, and if 15 amps or 20 amps circuits?  Age of house/electric might be able to assume some things.   Is there anything else working wonky?

Comment: If no breakers were tripped, what do you mean by "manual reset"?

Comment: By manual reset, I mean off then back on.

Comment: House is in Texas @ 1978. We had a lot of electrical storms this week, but there were no outages. Rewiring of circuits  was done 10 years ago per previous owner. I just bought the house. Micro (built in)and air fryer were on the same circuit. 20 amps. I’ve turned off 4 breakers where lights were not full strength ( wonky). Pool area, dining room, den , and kitchen.

Comment: Are the bulbs that are showing up orange incandescent, fluorescent, or LED?

Comment: Incandescent bulbs.

Comment: You need to call an electrician.

Comment: Are you sure that the breaker wasnt tripped? They wont fully turn off, it will just go slightly towards the middle and if you try to push it back to on it will be springy and not let you until you turn it off and back on.

Comment: The orange is common for a bad connection. Kitchen lights on the same circuit as the receptacles??? It could be a bad breaker like a stablock Or Zinsco but more common a bad connection at a receptacle adding the orange lights to the question instead of a comment would be helpful. A built in microwave and some lights would be ok but the air fryer on the counter top circuit is a gross overload.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out not to be an overload, but a bad leg coming into the meter box. Apparently, with all the rain, water had seeped into the underground box (which eventually connects into the meter box), causing arcing. So one leg was 120, the other 20; half the house wasn’t getting power. Being a first-time homeowner, it never occurred to me to check the meter box. I unnecessarily hired an electrician to diagnose a problem that was the power company’s responsibility. The power company repairman told me that if the meter is blank or the numbers aren’t moving, then that’s the indicator it’s on the power company side. I feel the electrician should have noticed that before he opened up the meter and charged a diagnostic fee.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like a common overloaded circuit problem and either the hot or the neutral failed at a receptacle. This is regularly caused by the use of backstabbed receptacles but a loose connection or broken wire are the leading causes other than a back stab. (It should be a 20 amp circuit and no back stabs)

Is the breaker that controls the receptacle for the air fryer and microwave a single or double?

identify all the receptacles on that circuit do any have power?

Usually with 2 large loads like a microwave and a fryer you may be right at the 2400w max for a 20 amp circuit breaker and the breaker will hold with higher wattages for a short time but any weak connections may burn open.

Work back in the direction of the service panel looking for a receptacle that has power. The failure will be there or the first device after that that is dead.
It could be the white or black wire.

How could it be a receptacle that works? The feed to this receptacle is good but the feed to the next one is bad. Or at the first non working the feed in is bad.

Once you identify the last good first non working turn the power off and pull those receptacles (they may not have been in use) but this is the most common failure point for a overloaded or circuit loaded to the max.

The problem could be in the service panel at the breaker or neutral bus but this is rare compared to at the receptacles

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The breaker is a single.I agree I probably overloaded the circuit, although I had run those two things previously without a problem, so didn’t think to add up the wattages. (My first home). Is it also common for other circuits to fail because of the overloaded kitchen circuit?

Comment: Josch the kitchen counter top circuits or small appliance circuits 2ea 20 amp are required by code having a built in microwave or kitchen lighting on the same circuit is a code violation, a built in microwave and lights can be on the same circuit.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

1. A broken circuit breaker that *should* have tripped.
2. A floating neutral connection, which would split the voltage unevenly between two sides of a 120-0-120 split circuit. This would be indicated by some of the lights in the house getting much *brighter*, while others *dimmed*
3. Aluminum wiring making poor contact, or other cause of high impedance in the circuit.

**All of these can cause a fire inside a wall.** Have an electrician check out the cause ASAP.

BTW, ["Texas has avoided federal regulation by establishing its own power grid,"](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/curious-texas/2021/02/16/how-did-texas-wind-up-on-its-own-electrical-grid-curious-texas-investigates/) so standards that apply to the rest of the United States of America don't necessarily apply there. [Aluminum house wiring was discontinued in the rest of the country in mid 1970's](https://www.howtolookatahouse.com/Blog/Entries/2020/3/when-did-they-stop-using-aluminum-wiring-in-houses.html) because it was prone to high-resistance connections, but that might not be true in your state.

Comment: The stuff with the Texas grid is all *utility* side -- most jurisdictions in Texas adopt the NEC just like the rest of the USA (albeit with local amendments in some places)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, tha6 may be, but I do not know at what point Texas phased out (no pun intended) Al domestic wiring. The information I found was "mid-1970's", and the house was built in 1978.

Comment: That depends entirely in local NEC amendments -- the NEC itself permits "new technology" AA-8000 series wire to be used for all branch, feeder, and service wiring (AA-1350/EC/"old technology" wire isn't allowed for the wire types used in indoor wiring, only for URD and other utility-ish things)